# Please tell me the correct way to sit seiza

Tags: technique

Is Seiza sitting cross-legged or is it sitting above your bent upper and lower legs which aren't crossed?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially kneeling all the way down so thighs touch calves. Some schools cross the big toes, some don't.

So the second description in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some common sitting positions. At my zendo, we sit in Seiza, Lotus, or Half-lotus.
[image: Here are some common sitting positions. At my zendo, we sit in Seiza, Lotus, or Half-lotus.]